# Give Eigen::Map output its own storage?

Tags: c++, eigen

So I want to use `Eigen::Map` to interpret my Input and than save it to the given output location. But as far as I know `Eigen::Map` itself is a Pointer and does not contain data? What is the workaround? And Yes in my case I really need to use Eigen::Map since I am not only reinterpreting the size.

Following short example, since the original code is too long:

```
void transformTo33Mat(const inst& in[], Eigen::MatrixXi* out){
// Goal I want to use Eigen::Map to reinterpret the data and than save the
// reinterpreted data to out
  *out = Eigen::Map<Matrix3i>(in);
}


int main{
  int array[9];
  for(int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) array[i] = i;
  Eigen::MatrixXi output;

  transformTo33Mat(&array, *output);
  return 0;
}
```

So I want to store the new interpreted matrix to output. But I think using `Eigen::Map` in this way would only pass a pointer of array? So if the array storage changes, my output would change right? Thats basically the reason why you cannot return an `Eigen::Map` ?

Because Map dows not own the data, as explained in [ReturnEigenMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38786856/returning-a-eigenmap-from-a-lambda)

Comment: `Eigen::Map` is a class which *contains* a pointer (and dimension information if they are not known at compile time). Your `transformTo33Mat` is completely valid (not the way you call it, though). Usually, you would pass `out` by reference and not by pointer (or return by value). But I don't understand what you actually want to do ...

Comment: @chtz Jeah maybe my example is not the best. So in the real code I have central data struct. I pass this data class by reference. But in this case I want to pass one of its member as pointer. `Struct->output`. And than in my `Function transformTo33Mat` I want to reinterpret some given input and save it to the output Pointer of the struct. But I cannot save the data to my Pointer using `Eigen::Map`, since `Eigen::Map` itself does not own the data and is only a pointer...

Comment: Assigning an `Eigen::Map` to an `Eigen::Matrix` performs a copy, in case that wasn't clear. So whether or not `Eigen::Map` owns the data does not matter. Does your problem persist?